# Hide Data Series in Pivot chart but not in Pivot Table

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I want to hide a data series in `Pivot chart` but not in `Pivot Table`.
As the `Pivot table` and `Pivot chart` are Inter related, making change in one affects the other.

I am looking for solution with out using VBA.

Comment: Create a copy of your pivot table and do the graph on one of them... I know, I know, you were expecting more...

Comment: @R3uK That is the current solution I have.When doubles the size of the file so looking for better solution.